# Do "chunked" pushes to remote Git repo?

Tags: git, github

We want to push a 20.00+ commit local Git repository to GitHub but it turns out that although the transfer itself is no problem GitHub doesn't actually process more than a 1000 commits at a time ("process" meaning that they'll link commits to issues etc).

So to be able to correctly transfer this repository and have it correctly processed we should transfer in "chunks" of no more than a 1000 at a time. But how?

We tried somehow moving back in history, moving forward in blocks and pushing each time, but we must be using the wrong "ordering" because this just results in lots of problems.

Comment: What kind of problems?

Comment: Things like:

    error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'
    hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
    hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
    hint: before pushing again.
    hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

(sorry for the mess, can't seem to get formatting to work here)

Comment: You can only add formatting in the question. It's editable and is the appropriate place to add further details you are being asked for.

Comment: That one is not really an error. Just a somewhat impolite warning that you _might_ be doing something wrong. In this case you are not, so you should just force it (`git push -f`).

Comment: error: I tried forcing but then the error changed to "too many dangling objects". (Which was one of the reasons I thought things were being pushed in the wrong "order" pushing children maybe before their parents exist. But that's just me guessing)

Comment: Could you provide exact quote for that error? It's strange, because push can't under any concievable circumstances create dangling objects at least as long as reflogs are enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided you are using bash you can run the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 20000 -900 0)
do
   git push origin master~$i:master
done
git push origin master:master
```

it will iterate from 20000 to 0 and iteratively push commits to the remote branch `master`.

`master~n` is Git syntax and denotes the *n'th commit before `master`*.

Comment: Almost there, but it's `git push [<repository> [<refspec...>]]`, so you have to mention repository and have to mention the target branch, because `HEAD~13261` is _not_ a refspec (it is only a commitish).

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed as well.

Comment: Ad edit: `HEAD~$i` is _not a refspec_. It will _not be accepted_. Because you can push revision, but you have to push it to a branch.

Comment: You could just make `git push origin master~$i:master` to say your local commit `master~$i` should go to the `master` remote branch. And then that would be great - no need to create `send` branch and all that.

Comment: oh, correct... Now I also understand what Jan Hudec was trying to say ;-)

Comment: Ok, sorry for the late response, I had to try it and figure out why it didn't work. So the problem with this solution is that it only works if you have a neat mostly "linear" commit history. In our case we have a repository that was created out of a merge of 8 other repositories so even though "git log" will return thousands of entries doing "git log master~X" will only allow us to go back 9 steps (the first commit of the new repository + the 8 merge commits for each of the component repositories)
And of course each merge contains many thousands of commits.

Comment: I'll mark this as the best response even though it didn't actually solve our problem. But I still hope it will help us get there via an alternative route. So thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

One usually pushes references to a remote, so you should `git reset` your `master` branch to any commit that's *elegible* to be commited (ie, it's less than 1000 commits from the begining of the repo or the last pushed commit). Say you've determined (using `tig` or `git log`) your 998th commit is `abd123124`, and 1980th commit is `bad1424`, you can:

```
$ git checkout -b real_master # create a 'backup' branch for not losing the reference
$ git checkout master
$ git reset abd123124 # set master to the 998th commit
$ git push origin master
$ git reset bad1424 # set master to the 1980th commit
$ git push origin master
```

And so on.

I think you shouldn't have any issue with the working tree, but if you do, `git checkout .` should solve it.

You surely can make any script for automating this commit finding thing, but if you know your repo's log size you can use `real_master~NUMBER` for resetting (say, your repo has **exactly** 20k commits, you can use `real_master~19000`, `real_master~180000`, etc).

Comment: There is no need to reset. You can push revisions.