# I want to add a 9.7 GB project to GitHUB

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push my local git into my remote but the project is too big:

```
MINGW64 ~/source/repos/DBO (master)
$ git config http.postBuffer 9370000000

MINGW64 ~/source/repos/DBO (master)
$ git push --set-upstream origin master
Enumerating objects: 149849, done.
Counting objects: 100% (149849/149849), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (94939/94939), done.
fatal: protocol error: bad line length 81925 MiB | 342.52 MiB/s
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Alejandro-HUB/DBO.git'

MINGW64 ~/source/repos/DBO (master)
```

I tried using this to increase GitHUB's file size limit but I think they may have a limit for how big the project can be:

```
$ git config http.postBuffer 9370000000
```

Is there any way for me to get my project into GitHUB?

Comment: I don't have much experience with this myself, but I did a quick bit of research and found this, which looks promising: [Upload file > 25 MB on Github](/q/61040990/4518341)

Comment: Very likely your project contains a lot of binary files, such as videos, pictures, sounds.. May be drawings in dwg or something like that. There is a module called git-lsf (large file storage), which can handle large binary files vesioning. Read more [here](https://git-lfs.github.com/).

Comment: Try chunked push: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21857171/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+chunks

Comment: GitHub have a project size limit of a few GB, well under your project's size. This is not configurable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your help and suggestions! I decided to use Azure Dev Ops and gradually push my project there since they are limited to 5GB at a time which makes the process faster than 2GB at a time.

Answer (score 4):

You can push such a project to GitHub, but only incrementally.  GitHub has a 2 GB limit on all pushes, which cannot be changed.  You can push it incrementally by doing something like this to push 5000 commits at a time:

```
$ git rev-list --reverse HEAD | \
  perl -ne 'print unless $i++ % 5000;' | \
  xargs -I{} git push origin {}:master
```

Once that completes, most of the objects will be pushed, and you should be able to push the rest of the data.

If you have a single commit which introduces data that's more than 2 GB, then you won't be able to push that to GitHub.  You'll have to split it up into smaller commits.

Also, [the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-postbuffer) explains why you shouldn't need to set `http.postBuffer` and why doing so will waste a huge amount of memory.  You should unset that value.

Comment: At 9.7Gb... Isn't there a repo size limit in addition to a push limit?

Comment: Yes, there is.  It is presently 100 GB, although you are strongly recommended not to even approach that size.  You'll receive warnings at 75 GB.