# How to write bash script to loop through a git fetch command

Tags: bash, git, git-fetch

I've been trying to fetch all branches of a git repository

using "git fetch"

but due to network issue it's failing

Then after searching for a while I tried

"git fetch --depth=n" , n = 1, 10, 20, .....

but this failed too even with value 1.
next attempt was

"git fetch origin 'branchname' --depth=n"

but I don't want to manually put this command every time.Would be a lot easier if I could find a bash-script to increase n by 100 and run this command in a loop.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the network issue? Does just take a long time and the network randomly fails sometimes or is it something else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21857171/7976758 See example for push. Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+chunked